# UnauthorizedAccessException with File.AppendAllText in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, file-io, file-permissions

I have recently started getting System.UnauthorizedAccessException errors when using File.AppendAllText to write to a shared drive on the network.  I think there were some changes to the network when this happened.  The code in my application hasn't changed.

I have asked our IT dept to grant me full permission to the folder.  I can see I have permissions for Modify, Read & Execute, Read, Write under my username if I navigate to the file and look at the Security tab under properties.  I am also part of a group with read, write and modify permissions to the folder.

This works without error in the same folder:

```
 File.WriteAllText(myFile, myText)
```

This generates a System.UnauthorizedAccessException error when it reaches the AppendallText:

```
         If File.Exists(myFile) = False Then
            ' Create a file to write to.
            Dim createText As String = logTime & " " & report_data
            File.WriteAllText(myFile, createText)
        Else
            Dim appendText As String = logTime & " " & report_data
            File.AppendAllText(myFile, appendText)
        End If
```

I have tried deleting the file and creating it again, that made no difference.
I tried File.SetAttributes(myFile, FileAttributes.Normal)
The IT dept can't see what the problem is.

I can manually open, change and modify the file.  The problem only arises if I am trying to do this programmatically.

Is there a different 'user' which tries to modify files? Could the file be open somehow, or would that generate a different error?

I'm using VB.NET 2012, .net framework 4.5, Windows 8.1

Comment: Is there an InnerException in the exception you are getting ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network changes were the problem.  It doesn't seem possible to resolve this as it is.  Instead I made a copy of the text data, append my new text to that, delete the file, and save the updated text to a new file.